# Outlook Calendar: Showing a day has gone already

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

Is there a way to show that a day has occurred? When I print my calendars out I like to cross out the days that have already happened and I wanted to know if there was a setting to do that for Outlook as well?

Answer (score 2):

This was asked on Microsoft's site and an answer was given that may help you. Click here to see it: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9c4cad00-80c5-43ac-9c06-4f595c8914f4/calendar-cross-or-mark-off-days-by-putting-x-on-them?forum=outlook.

The answer they gave is as follows:

> I have searched for this feature extensively and couldn't come up with
>   anything.  It simply doesn't exist and for some reason Microsoft won't
>   do anything about it.  I don't understand how it could be that
>   difficult.
>
> Anyway, I've come up with a solution that works for me, because I
>   don't really like having to look around the month view for where
>   today's date is.  I just created a new appointment named "Done" (for
>   days that are past) and categorized it in a new category called "Done
>   Days" which I put a black label on.  Of course, you can use red, pink,
>   green, or anything else that suits your fancy, but black shows up well
>   for me.  I then posted that appointment on a day in the past and set
>   it for "All Day" so that it wouldn't remind me.  If you click on the
>   appointment once, just so that it selects it, you can hit Ctrl+C to
>   copy and then click on any other day, and hit Ctrl+V to paste it into
>   any past days.
>
> This way, any past days have a black bar through them that says "Done"
>   and at the end of a day, all you have to do is select one of those
>   bars, and copy and paste it to the current day.  Maybe it's just me,
>   but I think it's kind of satisfying to check off a day this way.

Comment: This method has been used by others following this answer and said that it worked well for them too